# How to insert link tags between head tags on HTML using SimpleHtmlDom

Tags: php, html-parsing

I'm trying to manipulate HTML codes by the use of [simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net). This is i've got so far. I could create a new file or turn the *index.html* to *index.php* and copy the head tag from the index.html. The problem is, how could I insert the link tags:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

between the head tags?

```
<?php
# create and load the HTML
include('simple_html_dom.php');
// get DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('D:\xampp\htdocs\solofile\index.html');
$indexFile ='index.php';
$openIndexFile = fopen($indexFile,'a');
//find head tag
foreach($html->find('head') as $e)
{
 $findHead = $e->outertext;
 fwrite($openIndexFile, "\n" .$findHead. "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) (Section : How to access the HTML element's attributes? / Tips) :

```
// Append a element
$e->outertext = $e->outertext . '<div>foo<div>';
```

Which you may use like this :

```
$e = $html->find('head')->innertext; // Should take all HTML inside <head></head> w/o <head></head
$e = $e.'<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />'; // inserting the CSS at the end of what's inside <head></head>
```

I didn't try but maybe (depending on the class) you may need to make the first line into 2.

```
$f = $html->find('head');
$e = $f->innertext;
```

But you get the idea, right? ;)

Comment: Ooops, like all the HTML inside <head> </head>? So,all the html tags will be deleted? that's not i have in mind. since i just to insert the line $e. but not delete the whole html lines inside <head></head> tags.

Comment: @Stupefy101 : `// inserting the CSS at the end of what's inside <head></head>` means it'll add the `link` after all html. It shouldn't delete anything in there (if simplehtmldom is done right.)