# How to make all src strings global in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, browser, local, file-get-contents

I am writing a web browser in PHP, for devices (such as the Kindle) which do not support multi-tab browsing. Currently I am reading the page source with file_get_contents(), and then echoing it into the page. My problem is that many pages use local references (such as < img src='image.png>'), so they all point to pages that don't exist. What I want to do is locate all src and href tags and prepend the full web address to any that do not start with "http://" or "https://". How would I do this?

Comment: I believe the terminology that you're looking for here (and will most likely get you more correct answers) is *non-relative*. (*How to make all src strings non-relative in PHP?* or something similar)

Comment: how would you correctly reference urls to images within the remote css files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `<base href="http://example.com/" />`

at the head of the page

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755570/how-to-insert-link-tags-between-head-tags-on-html-using-simplehtmldom) will help you insert it to the `<head></head>` section

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't use the innertext because it is not being returned as a html element but rather as a string; this is what I have: `<?php
$url = "http://www.example.com";
$str = file_get_contents($url);
$matche = array();
$pos = str_replace("<head>", '<head>\n<base href="http://www.example.com" />', $str);
echo $pos; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Like [elibyy suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624698/how-to-make-all-src-strings-global-in-php/7624754#7624754), I too would recommend using the `base` tag. Here's a way to do it with PHP's native [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):

```
// example url
$url = 'http://example.com';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile( $url );

// first let's find out if there a base tag already
$baseElements = $doc->getElementsByTagName( 'base' );

// if so, skip this block
if( $baseElements->length < 1 )
{
    // no base tag found? let's create one
    $baseElement = $doc->createElement( 'base' );
    $baseElement->setAttribute( 'href', $url );
    $headElement = $doc->getElementsByTagName( 'head' )->item( 0 );
    $headElement->appendChild( $baseElement );
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

---

Having said this however; are you sure you are aware of how ambitious your goal is?

For instance, I don't think this is exactly what you really need at all, as your application is basically acting as a proxy. Therefor you will probably want to route, at least, all user-clickable links through your application, and not route them directly to the original links at all, because I presume you want to keep the user in your tabbed application, and not break out of it.

Something like:

```
http://yourapplication.com/resource.php?resource=http://example.com/some/path/
```

Now, this could of course be achieved by basically doing what you requested, and in stead of prepending it with either, `http://` or `https://` prepend with something such that it results in above example url.

However, how are you gonna discern what resources to do this with, and what resources not? If you take this approach for all resources in the page, your application will quickly become a full fletched proxy, thereby becoming very resource intensive.

Hopefully I've given you a brief starter for some things to take into consideration.

Comment: True. I hadn't thought of that. I now have: ` <?php
$url=$_GET["url"];
$str = file_get_contents($url);
$pos = str_replace("src='", "src='".$url.'/', $str);
$pos = str_replace('src="', 'src="'.$url.'/', $pos);
$pos = str_replace("href='", "href='".$url.'/', $pos);
$pos = str_replace('href="', 'href="'.$url.'/', $pos);
$pos = str_replace($url.'/http://', 'http://', $pos);
$pos = str_replace($url.'"http://', '"http://', $pos);
$pos = str_replace($url."'http://", "'http://", $pos);
echo $pos; ?>` , but I don't know how to actually proxy files if they aren't html - what do I do with images?